# How to combine to different firebase query streams into one stream?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I've reached a roadblock while trying to create a chat app. I want to merge two different streams to one, to create my Chat Screen. For example-

If `user1` sends a message to `user2`, it gets stored in-

`FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(user1).collection("data").doc(user2).collection("chats")`

Similarly, if `user2` sends a message to `user1`, it gets stored in-

`FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(user2).collection("data").doc(user1).collection("chats")`

All the chats sent by a user are stored in the chats collection, inside the a doc named the receivers uid.

So essentially, I need both the data insede-`FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(user1).collection("data").doc(user2).collection("chats")` (to get the chats sent by user1 to user 2) and `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(user1).collection("data").doc(user2).collection("chats")` (to get chats sent by user2 to user1) to create the chat screen.

I want to know how to merge these two streams together into one, so I can use the data to create the chat widgets. So far this is what i've got-

Note: Continuing the analogy, `user1`'s uid is `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid`, and `user2`'s uid is stored in `widget.uid`.

```
StreamBuilder(
          //To get messaages sent by the current user to user2 or widgets.uid
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("users")
              .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
              .collection("data")
              .doc(widget.uid)    
              .collection("chats")
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context,
              AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>
                  UserMessagesSnapshots) {
            if (UserMessagesSnapshots.connectionState ==
                ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const LoadingScreen();
            } else {

              return StreamBuilder(
                  //to get messages sent by user2 to user1
                  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection("users")
                      .doc(widget.uid)
                      .collection("data")
                      .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
                      .collection("chats")
                      .snapshots(),
                  builder: (context,
                      AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>
                          FriendMessagesSnapshot) {
                    if (FriendMessagesSnapshot.connectionState ==
                        ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return const LoadingScreen();
                    } else {
                         //and here i have both the streams. 
                    }
                  });
            }
          },
        ),
```

Comment: Rxdart is the best option https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart or streamZip from the package async

Comment: But to create a chat don't do it like that. Use a cloud function de detect when a message arrive on the server and send it to the right personne. Use https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @mariofrancios!

I created this function to merge the streams to one-

```
Stream<List<QuerySnapshot>> getMessages() {
    Stream userMessages = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .collection("data")
        .doc(widget.uid)
        .collection("chats")
        .snapshots();
    Stream friendMessages = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(widget.uid)
        .collection("data")
        .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
        .collection("chats")
        .snapshots();
    return StreamZip([(userMessages as dynamic), (friendMessages as dynamic)]);
  }
```

And listened to it like this-

```
...StreamBuilder(
          stream: getMessages(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<QuerySnapshot>> snap) {
            if (snap.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const LoadingScreen();
            } else {
              // access the data with snap.data![n].docs[n].data()
            }
          },
        ),
```